# How to invoke QBrush.setTexture() with QPixmap on QGraphicsRectItem?

Tags: qt, qpainter

I am trying to use `QBrush.setTexture()` to update `QGraphicsRectItem` with a .png background. But I cannot set the exact size to fit the `QGraphicsRectItem` with the `QPixMap`.

```
brush->setTexture((QPixmap(":/images/h_shutdown.png"))
.scaled(70,30,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
```

But the .png always piled to extend from center crossed.

Do you have any suggestions?

[QGrahpicsRectItem with backround png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzY5H.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that if you fiddled around with the rectangle coordinates and the image size enough, you might eventually get this to work, but it's always going to try to tile the texture. If your rectangle changes shape, or you have user interactions with it, it's just going to get more frustrating and time-consuming to make it work.

I'd recommending abandoning trying to use the brush for this. Instead, subclass QGraphicsRectItem and paint the PNG image yourself. The QPainter commands for drawing images (drawImage) and rectangles (drawRect) are very easy to use, and then you have complete control. Don't forget to call QGraphicsRectItem::paint from within your derived class's paint method after painting the PNG. Otherwise, the rectangle will disappear.

You could also subclass QGraphicsPixmapItem. It would be responsible for drawing the PNG file, and then you'd have to paint the rectangle.

Alternately, you can subclass QGraphicsItem and do all of the painting yourself, which is also very easy. Early on in my Qt experience, I avoided subclassing QGraphicsItem and focused on using the built-in shapes for everything because I didn't want to dig into the painting calls. It was actually a mistake and introduced a lot of unnecessary complexity that I would've avoided if I'd just created my own graphics item classes rather than trying to force the built-in ones to do everything I needed. The QPainter calls are very easy and very complete, and I'd strongly encourage exploring that instead.

Subclassing QGraphicsItem rather than either QGraphicsRectItem or QGraphicsPixmapItem gives you much more control over the drawing, so that's the routine I would recommend for your ultimate solution. However, if you'd like to make changes in smaller steps, then start by subclassing QGraphicsRectItem, experiment with that, and then move to subclassing QGraphicsItem. Which works best will depend on your exact needs.